# Can I reuse Facebook OAuth token to open a Facebook page in a browser?

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

I'm thinking this may not be possible... but I have an Android application that is using the Facebook Graph API to get some information. They can tap the view there and open up a browser with a full-fledged Facebook page, but it asks the user to log in again.

I'd like to be able to skip the initial sign in (I know the browser can remember your login). Is there a way I can use the OAuth token from the Graph API to authorize for the Facebook web page?

I did try appending "access_token=..." to the query string, but that was fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the facebook OAuth token on other platforms like this.

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=***here comes your accesstoken***

Off course you will only be able to call api functions (and only those where you have permission for)

I'm not aware of a permission that allows you to do a full-fledged web-site login :-).